# Назначить комбинацию клавиш для webbrowser - C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser, клавиатура

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли как-то назначить определенную комбинацию клавиш для webbrowser, чтобы "пкм-сохранить изображение как..." исполнялось после нажатия указанных клавиш, а не после щелчка правой кнопкой мыши и выбора соответствующего пункта из меню?

Answer (score 0):

Если отображается изображение в браузере -- просто сейв открытую страницу. Оно сохранит само изображение потому как оно и открыто вместо хтмл-страницы :)

.....

Если же открыта страница -- то каким макаром оно должно знать какое из изображений сохранять, если на странице их может быть хоть сотня хоть две?

Я могу предположить следующий вариант: сделай поиск по всем имедж тегам `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")` в документе и сохраняй имедж с самым большим разрешением. Возможно иногда в таком случае оно будет сохранять бекграунды некоторых сайтов. Потому советую сделать более сложную выборку по своему усмотрению :)

я с веб-браузером не знаком, потому могу предположить что невозможно достать подгруженую картинку как битмап(а может и возможно, проверь сначала!). Если это опасение оправдается, в таком случае достань все src картинок и качай каждую из них кодом вроде

```
try
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request =
        System.Net.WebRequest.Create(webUrl);

    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    Bitmap bitmapImg = new Bitmap(responseStream);

    return bitmapImg;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException)
{
}
```

Ну а прилепить хоткей на вызов метода в апликуху, должно быть, вообще не проблема :)